# Is is possible to mix different alignments in an NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a simple question concerning `NSMutableAttributedString` (or `NSAttributedString`).

Is it possible to do the following.
Supposing the string I want to display is: "Hello\nWorld"
(*Hello* on the first line an *World* on the second)

Is it possible to have the first line (*Hello*) left aligned and the second line (*World*) right aligned?
If the answer is YES, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `NSParagraphStyle`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let paragraphStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle1.alignment = .left

    let paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle2.alignment = .right

    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Hello \n World")

    if let range = attrString.string.range(of: "Hello") {
        let nsrange = attrString.string.nsRange(from: range)
        attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle1], range: nsrange)
    }

    if let range = attrString.string.range(of: "World") {
        let nsrange = attrString.string.nsRange(from: range)
        attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle2], range: nsrange)
    }

    self.label.textAlignment = .right
    self.label.attributedText = attrString
}
```

Output:
[image: output]